# change how mvc3 razor renders a newly created view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

By default whenever you create a strongly typed "Insert Type" view using mvc3 razor it renders the html similar to

```
       <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
```

Which is inside a fieldset. I don't really want this behavior is it possible to replace the default style of html to my own? I dont want fieldsets and I want to remove the css class details for the div tags as I think its a little of an overkill for what I need.

Any suggestions would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the [corresponding T4 templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/01/29/t4-templates-a-quick-start-guide-for-asp-net-mvc-developers.aspx). For example on my machine they are located in the following folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 3\CodeTemplates\AddView\CSHTML\
```

Modifying them would be global for the machine.

You can also modify/add new them per project. So in your project you could create the following folder:

```
~/CodeTemplates/AddView/CSHTML/Edit.tt
```